# How to place 3D object on horizontal plane automatically (without tapping) in iOS 12?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm working on an app with AR feature. I want to be able to place a 3D model that I have on a horizontal plane that has been detected. So inside the renderer(didAdd) delegate function, I added a node for my 3D model, and set its position to the center of the plane anchor. However, when I run the app to test it, my model is floating on top of the plane instead of standing directly on top of it. My guess is that there is some translation that needs to be done with the coordinates, but don't know about the details. Can somebody give me some pointers?

Comment: it is depend on your 3D model. If you put cube it will be placed on top of plane. You need manually set translation as per your model bounding box

Comment: Please share your `renderer(didAdd)` code and a screen shot of the result, so we can help you better.